# Probability - Expectation value and Covariance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, variance, expected-value

A group of $n = 10$ men exchange their gloves randomly (altogether there are 20 gloves).
Let $X_i$ be the random variable which attains the value 1 if the $i-th$ man got at least one of his gloves back and it attains the value 0 otherwise. Set $p = E(X_i)$ and $σ^2 = Var(X_i)$.

Observe that $p = \frac{37}{190}$ and that $Var (X_i) = \frac{5661}{190^2}$.
Let $b$ be the probability that for $i\ne j$ both the $i-th$ and $j-th$ men got at least one of their gloves back.

Show that $b = \frac {1157}{{20 \choose 2}{18 \choose 2}}$.

1.) Let $X$ be the total number of men who received at least one of their gloves. Find $E(X)$.

2.) Calculate $Var(X).$ You may write it as an expression in $p$, $σ^2$ and $b.$

At first I just thought that $E(X)=np=10\frac{37}{190}$ and then $Var(X)=npq=10\cdot 37\cdot\frac{153}{190^2}$ but now I am not sure about that, as the events do intersect: if someone takes gloves of someone else, then someone else has nothing to choose from. However, I do not know how to count these. Could you help me, please? Thanks

Comment: What's the definition of $b$? The expectation is correct, as it's just linearity. For the variance, consider the formula using the covariance, as it's not clear if the $X_i$ are independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations of $p$, $\sigma^2$ and $\mathbb EX$ are okay.

Covariance is bilinear, so that by symmetry:

$$\mathsf{Var}(X)=\mathsf{Cov}(\sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i,\sum_{j=1}^{10}X_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{10}\sum_{j=1}^{10}\mathsf{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=10\mathsf{Var}(X_1)+90\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=$$$$10\sigma^2+90(\mathbb EX_1X_2-\mathbb EX_1\mathbb EX_2)=10\sigma^{10}+90(P(X_1=X_2=1)-P(X_1=1)P(X_2=1))=$$$$10\sigma^2+90(b-p^2)$$

Here $b=P(X_1=X_2=1)$ so it remains to find $P(X_1=X_2=1)$

**edit**:

Let $Z_{1}$ denote the number of gloves taken by person 1 that 
belong to person 1.

Let $Y_{1}$ denote the number of gloves taken by person 1 that belong
to person 2.

Then:

$$P\left(X_{1}=X_{2}=1\right)=$$$$P\left(X_{2}=1\mid Z_{1}=2\right)P\left(Z_{1}=2\right)+$$$$P\left(X_{2}=1\mid Z_{1}=1\wedge Y_{1}=0\right)P\left(Z_{1}=1\wedge Y_{1}=0\right)+$$$$P\left(X_{2}=1\mid Z_{1}=1\wedge Y_{1}=1\right)P\left(Z_{1}=1\wedge Y_{1}=1\right)$$

This with

- $P\left(X_{2}=1\mid Z_{1}=2\right)=1-P\left(X_{2}=0\mid Z_{1}=2\right)=1-\frac{16}{18}\frac{15}{17}$
- $P\left(X_{2}=1\mid Z_{1}=1\wedge Y_{1}=0\right)=1-P\left(X_{2}=0\mid Z_{1}=1\wedge Y_{1}=0\right)=1-\frac{16}{18}\frac{15}{17}$
- $P\left(X_{2}=1\mid Z_{1}=1\wedge Y_{1}=1\right)=1-P\left(X_{2}=0\mid Z_{1}=1\wedge Y_{1}=1\right)=1-\frac{17}{18}\frac{16}{17}$
- $P\left(Z_{1}=2\right)=\frac{2}{20}\frac{1}{19}$
- $P\left(Z_{1}=1\wedge Y_{1}=0\right)=\frac{2}{20}\frac{16}{19}+\frac{16}{20}\frac{2}{19}$
- $P\left(Z_{1}=1\wedge Y_{1}=1\right)=\frac{2}{20}\frac{2}{19}+\frac{2}{20}\frac{2}{19}$

Comment: So than P(X1=1|X2=1) is equal to probability of intersection of these events divided by p. But isn't the probability of intersection defined as b=1157/(190*153)?

Comment: I have made an edit (because finding $P(X_1=2\mid X_1=1)$ was a bit more complicated than I thought). Does this help?

Comment: I still do not understand it completely. I counted this: P(Z=1)=36/190 and P(Z=2)=1/190. 

P(X2=1∣Z=2)=(2*16+1)/153

But P(X2=1∣Z=1) makes me problem. I think that it is similar to problem above, just there are  four cases when the first man picked one his glove and one glove of the second man, so that it is equal to 33-4=29. But then I got in total less than 1157. Could you tell me what is wrong, please?

Comment: Again I underestimated the complexity. I edited to provide a way to calculate $P(X_1=X_2=1)$. Do check me on mistakes, though.

Comment: Thank you very much! I calculated it and I got 1289/((20C2)(18C2)). But it should be 1157/((20C2)(18C2)), according to the task. Do you think it might be just wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but I found an error (and repaired). $P(Z_1=1\wedge Y_1=0)\neq\frac2{20}\frac{18}{20}+\frac{18}{20}\frac2{19}$ as I first said. $18$ on RHS must be replaced by $16$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that. Thank you very much! You were extremely helpful!